# Why is my pow result always zero?

Tags: c, printf

In my code, squaring the variable `R` always gives zero.
It does not matter if it's `pow(R, 2)` or `R*R`.
Why does that happen?
(If I change it to float, it works, but I need it to be a double for the precision.)

This is the code:

```
int main () {

    double R,PI,a;
    PI = 3.14159;
    scanf(" %d", &R);
    a = PI * (pow(R,2));
    printf ( "A= %0.4d \n", a );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hmm, try removing the space before the %d

Comment: @user3121023: Yes, and in the `printf` too, although the `l` is optional there.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Do you have the required `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <math.h>` at the top? If not, you need them. If you do, then please update the question to show us the actual code you're compiling.

Comment: I do have both, sorry about that

Comment: @CH4B Please learn to use a debugger. It would have told you that `a` is not zero and you would have known that the problem lies with the `printf` statement.

Comment: @CH4B Also, I see you have not yet voted, despite its [importance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). So, just so you know, in addition to accepting answers, you can express your opinion through the little triangles.

Comment: I would love to upvote. But i do not have enough reputation, I'm totes sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier in `scanf` and `printf`.

The `%d` format specifier expects the address of an `int` for `scanf`, and an `int` for `printf`.  You're instead passing in the address of a `double` and a `double` respectively.  Using the wrong format specifiers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to use `%lf` in `scanf` and `%f` in `printf` for a `double`:

```
scanf("%lf", &R);
a = PI * (pow(R,2));
printf ( "A= %0.4f \n", a );
```